# Sum Of column against id.in (1:6:3) this format

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql, oracle-apex-5.1

my Ui return id in this format 1:6:3 so i want to sum the value corresponding to that id. example if id return is = 1:6:3
then output will= 100+50+140=290
[image]

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle (plsql)?

Comment: Your question is not making any sense

Comment: Is the expected result 100 + 50 + 140 = 290?

Comment: i am using sql.

Comment: jarlh yes 290..i want the same

Comment: Please [edit] your question to remove either the MySQL or Oracle tags. Also please [edit] it to explain in more detail what you mean by `(1:6:3)` and how you get that result from the table you show.

Comment: @arman, Which programming language you use ?

Comment: actually i am working on oracle apex.. so i can use both plsql and sql

Comment: @arman, so first convert those : separated value to comma separated and then use it in your query.

Answer (score 0):

How about `SELECT SUM(value) FROM table WHERE ID IN (1,6,3)` ?

Comment: is the 1:6:3 is your string ?

Comment: alpesh it is in number

Comment: SQL does not understand **:** seperated value for in query, it expect to be comma (**,**) seperated value only, you have to convert that colon separated value to comma separated value (1,6,3) and then you can try

Answer (score 0):

Took some time to figure out what's the question. I think I got it now - it is about Apex and its "capability" to allow multiple selection from, for example, a select list or shuttle item. When you do that, those *multiple values* are represented as a colon-separated string.

If we suppose that it was a select list item, it requires two values: display and return. The resulting string contains those *return* values, which means that you selected several items whose return values were 1, 6 and 3 and - as described above - stored as `1:6:3`.

In order to do something with them - in your example, sum values from the table - you'll have to first parse that string into rows and join the result with the "real" table (the one whose image you posted). Let's call it the TEST table; here it is:

```
SQL> create table test (id number, value number, name varchar2(2));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test
  2    select 1, 100, 'a' from dual union
  3    select 2, 110, 'b' from dual union
  4    select 3, 140, 'c' from dual union
  5    select 4, 203, 'd' from dual union
  6    select 5, 230, 'e' from dual union
  7    select 6, 50 , 'f' from dual;

6 rows created.
```

In Apex, you'd do it as follows: P1_ITEM is a Page 1 item that contains the '1:6:3' string:

```
select sum(t.value) result
from test t join (select regexp_substr(:P1_ITEM, '[^:]+', 1, level) id
                  from dual
                  connect by level <= regexp_count(:P1_ITEM, ':') + 1
                 ) a on a.id = t.id;
```

Just to demonstrate it in SQL*Plus, this is the result:

```
SQL> select sum(t.value) result
  2  from test t join (select regexp_substr('&&P1_ITEM', '[^:]+', 1, level) id
  3                    from dual
  4                    connect by level <= regexp_count('&&P1_ITEM', ':') + 1
  5                   ) a on a.id = t.id;
Enter value for p1_item: 1:6:3

    RESULT
----------
       290

SQL>
```